# White space sometimes is not working in content-editable div

Tags: html, css

Sometimes the white space is not working in a content-editable div, but sometimes it is working. While typing a white space in the content-editable div the white space character suddenly stops working by not showing up, but key down event is calling. What is happening here? How can I fix this?

Comment: you might want to check your css, the div name will also affect the padding(white space)

Comment: but sometimes it is working. it stops working not all the time

Comment: yes it might be some part of the class or div that you might have overlook. It will be best if you show your code and screenshot your web in the question. It will help other to understand better and able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

make your div element class with below css styles

```css
.divElement{
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```